# How to add nice effects to my menu in Unity

Tags: c#, unity, graphic-effects

I have a simple menu but I would like to spice it up with some of what I thought would be simple effects. I have 4 buttons that are just rectangle with some GUIText centered on the button and when the button is clicked or even when the button first shows up on the screen I would like it to animate by flipping on the x-axis.

Here is the sample buttons from my game.

[image: Here is the sample button image from the game]

So I would like for it to flip when the buttons are first initiated or when the player clicks. I figured that since I was using unity this could be a simple task but I found out that GUIText cannot be rotated so even if I figure out how to rotate the quad that is the background the text won't do anything.

To sum this all up, how can I add a nice flipping effect to these buttons? Do I need to remove the GUIText and if so what can replace them but still keep the buttons looking nice? Is there even an alternative to GUIText?

Comment: Comments removed. Comments are not for suggestions about technology, or potential solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not practical using the current GUI system. Ideally you'd wait for the [new GUI system coming in 4.6](http://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/05/28/overview-of-the-new-ui-system/), which supports animation and a number of other features.

However, if you need to get this working now, don't use the GUI system. Add a textured quad to your scene and interact with it the same way you would a GUI element. The textured quad can be rotated easily.

The easiest way to create the textures for your quads is to use a paint program. Alternatively you can create a custom library for adding textures of individual letters. This can get pretty complicated. There are some existing libraries on the asset store for this purpose already if you'd rather use those.

Comment: I will probably just wait then. Does anyone have an idea of when 4.6 will be released or at least a working beta?

Comment: Word is it'll likely be before their Unite conference (August 20-22). So, sometime within the next month hopefully.

Comment: Ah wonderful, that makes me very happy then. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Comments removed. Comments are not for suggestions about technology, or potential solutions. –  Byte56♦ 21 hours ago . What is this answer if not a suggestion for a technology?

Comment: @sEnC There is a difference between answers and comments. The deleted comments contained links to various specific libraries for Unity GUIs. I'd be fine if something like that were in an answer. But that's no what the comments are for.

Comment: What the question asks is possible in reasonably practical manner using GUI.matrix.